# How creation of folders inside of plank be done in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS while retaining in them all the features of plank?

Tags: plank

I am very happy with what plank has to offer but I am also looking for ways on how can we create folders inside plank. If I want to group application together based on type, this could be very helpful feature. Like if I want to make **launcher application group** of games, office, shopping application group, etc, etc can this be done inside plank?  Extremely desired to have this. Like it opens on one click inside and closes in one click outside.

(Why I am trying to do this is because it will eliminate the need to go inside of app section altogether, except only rarely to add app launchers inside plank.)

Answer (score 0):

To create application launcher groups in Plank Dock, create folders somewhere on your system for each group you want to create, e.g. "Games", "Office", ... Then populate each of these folders with the `.desktop` launchers of the programs you want to include, for example:
[image]
You can find most `.desktop` files of your applications in the folder /usr/share/applications. Those from applications installed as a snap are in /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/.

Finally, drag the folders to Plank to add it to the dock. Clicking it will reveal a list of the applications that you can launch:
[image]

Comment: I have followed this now. It is good. Thank you for answering. Few queries I had related to this: This peculiar feature is available in android where we can make folders, but in it with one single click the folder items pop out with icon image!! Is that effect possible here with magnification on cursor hover over them? I may be dreaming too much but it would  make a very appealing feature if available. Thank you very much. :)